# How to identify a domain

Tags: flutter, dart

you need to do something similar:

```
Strting str = 'google.com'; //it will be a dynamic string

if(str = domain){
//Some method
}else{}
```

How to determine whether String is the site domain or just text? I am making a browser string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can validate given String is URL or not in dart by below,

```
bool _validURL = Uri.parse(str).isAbsolute; //true valid URL
```

or

```
Uri.tryParse(str)?.hasAbsolutePath ?? false; //true valid url
```

or by **RegEx**

```
var urlPattern = r"(https?|http)://([-A-Z0-9.]+)(/[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:‌​,.;]*)?";
var match = new RegExp(urlPattern, caseSensitive: false).firstMatch(str);
match = RegExp(urlPattern, caseSensitive: false).firstMatch(str);
```

or

```
String myURL = "google.com";
var matchCaseOne = new RegExp("^(http[s]?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|ftp:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|www\\.){1}([0-9A-Za-z-\\.@:%_\+~#=]+)+((\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)(/(.)*)?(\\?(.)*)?", caseSensitive: false).firstMatch(myURL);
var matchCaseTwo = new RegExp("^([0-9A-Za-z-\\.@:%_\+~#=]+)+((\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)(/(.)*)?(\\?(.)*)?", caseSensitive: false).firstMatch(myURL);
if(matchCaseOne !=null || matchCaseTwo !=null){
  print("valid URL");
}else{
  print("Not Valid URL");
}

//tested below URL's

https://google.com
http://google.com
ftp://google.com
www.google.com
https://www.google.com
http://www.google.com
ftp://www.google.com
google.com
```

Comment: this is a check if the String has http or https. If I enter google.com, the response is false. I need to check if the string is a domain.

Comment: Edited my answer check last regExp example @Samoilov

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the validate package from memory it can validate a domain.